# NodeJS - fs.exists() throws error but file is there?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I try to check if a file (a css-file for example) is existing on the server:

```
// parse url and extract URL path
var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;  


fs.exists(pathname, function (exist) {

    // if the file is not found, return 404
    if(!exist) {  
        console.log('NOT EXISTING: '+pathname);
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end(`File ${pathname} not found!`);
        return;
    }

..... blah blah 
}
```

the file is there but the output is:
`NOT EXISTING: /assets/css/bootstrap.min.css`

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this file in the same folder with `/assets`?

Comment: fs.exists() is deperecated in the lates node version try using fs.stat() for more click this link https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_options_callback

Comment: @cenkebret .. yes the executed-js-file is in the root where also the assets-folder is

Comment: Is 'pathname' the full path or a relative path to the root?  If its the later then it will fail as the fs.exists expects the full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `__dirname` infront of you path:

var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

```
fs.exists(__dirname + pathname, function (exist) {

    // if the file is not found, return 404
    if(!exist) {  
        console.log('NOT EXISTING: '+pathname);
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end(`File ${pathname} not found!`);
        return;
    }

..... blah blah 
}
```

When the path starts with `/` NodeJS will look for a file, starting from the root of your OS. By providing `__dirname` you are telling NodeJS to search from your current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use **__dirname** & **path.join (url)** to create an absolute path:

```
path.join(__dirname, url)
```